# _CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have done various ways to create a cached product list then display with a list, but till now still not working, can anyone help me

My Json fromCache

```
"[{"id":"2911","nama":"Abcd1","url":"myUrl"},{"id":"2910","nama":"Abcd2","url":"myUrl"},{"id":"2911","nama":"Abcd3","url":"myUrl"},{"id":"2549","nama":"Abcd4","url":"myUrl"}]"
```

My Code

```
  Future<List<ApiBookmark>> fetchApiBookmark() async {
  var adaCache = await APICacheManager().isAPICacheKeyExist('bookmark');
  if (adaCache) {
    print('ada');
    var cacheData = await APICacheManager().getCacheData('bookmark');
    var fromCache = '[' + cacheData.syncData + ']';

    List jsonResponse = fromCache as List;

    return jsonResponse
        .map((e) => ApiBookmark(id: e.id, nama: e.nama, url: e.url))
        .toList();
  } else {
    print('tidak ada');
    throw Exception('Failed to load bookmark');
  }
}

class ApiBookmark {
  final String id;
  final String nama;
  final String url;

  const ApiBookmark({
    required this.id,
    required this.nama,
    required this.url,
  });

  factory ApiBookmark.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ApiBookmark(
      id: json['id'],
      nama: json['nama'],
      url: json['url'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
List<ApiBookmark> listApi = <ApiBookmark>[];
Future<List<ApiBookmark>> fetchApiBookmark() async {
  listApi.clear();
  var fromCache = '''[{"id":"2911","nama":"Abcd1","url":"myUrl"},
      {"id":"2910","nama":"Abcd2","url":"myUrl"},
      {"id":"2911","nama":"Abcd3","url":"myUrl"},
      {"id":"2549","nama":"Abcd4","url":"myUrl"}]''';
  final jsonData = json.decode(fromCache);

  for (var item in jsonData) {
    listApi.add(ApiBookmark.fromJson(item));
  }
  for (var item in listApi) {
    print("${item.id} ${item.nama} ${item.url}");
  }
  return listApi;
}
```

then you can implement **"APICacheManager()"**